# How to check if JSON key exists or not in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

We have a JSON object like

```
{
"field1": {
        "display": "abc",
        "value": "def"
    },
    "field2": {
        "display": "abc2"
    },
    "field3": {
        "display": "abc3",
        "value": "def1"
    }
}
```

I want to store value only if the value key exist and keep as empty string if value key is not existent

Eg. i am trying this , but yeah it fails because field2 doesn't have a value key , not sure how can i achieve this

```
@sampleJsonObject['field2']['value'] ?  @sampleJsonObject['field2']['value'] : ""
```

How can i achieve that?

Comment: what does `key` mean in your statement `@sampleJsonObject[key['field2']]['value'])`?

Comment: You've posted a hash there. If you are using a hash you can just use `obj.key?(key_to_check)` which will return true or false if the key is present

Comment: Yeah it worked fine, it returned null when i started using it has hash, thanks al ot all for your help :)

Comment: Your question is unclear to me because there is no JSON in your question. What is `@sampleJsonObject` and `@locations_to_map`?

Comment: @spickermann sorry for all the confusion, have edited it , the trick was to use hash

Comment: may be you can do something like the following 

`@sampleJsonObject.each_key{|key| p @sampleJsonObject[key].key?(:value) ? @sampleJsonObject[key][:value] : '' }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert json into hash using [json](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.1/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html)

```
[21] pry(main)> require 'json'
=> false
[22] pry(main)> @sampleJsonObject = '{"field1": { "display": "abc", "value": "def"  }, "field2": { "display": "abc2"}, "field3": {"display": "abc3","value": "def1"}}'
=> "{\"field1\": { \"display\": \"abc\", \"value\": \"def\"  }, \"field2\": { \"display\": \"abc2\"}, \"field3\": {\"display\": \"abc3\",\"value\": \"def1\"}}"
[23] pry(main)> @JsonToHashObject = JSON.parse(@sampleJsonObject)
=> {"field1"=>{"display"=>"abc", "value"=>"def"}, "field2"=>{"display"=>"abc2"}, "field3"=>{"display"=>"abc3", "value"=>"def1"}}
[24] pry(main)> @JsonToHashObject['field1']['value']
=> "def"
[25] pry(main)> @JsonToHashObject['field2']['value']
=> nil
[26] pry(main)> @JsonToHashObject['field2']['display']
=> "abc2"
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest to use a ruby's hash to manipulate the object data:

```rb
hashy = {
  "field1": {
    "display": 'abc',
    "value": 'def'
  },
  "field2": {
    "display": 'abc2'
  },
  "field3": {
    "display": 'abc3',
    "value": 'def1'
  }
}
```

Or if it's a json string:

```rb
hashy = JSON.parse('{"field1": {"display": "abc","value": "def"},"field2": {"display": "abc2"},"field3": {"display": "abc3","value": "def1"}}')
```

You can try this in irb:

```rb
h[:field2][:value] ? 'value exists' : 'value don\'t exist and returns nil'
```

And it will return `"value don't exist and returns nil"`

You can set your `value` key with an empty value asking if the value is nil:

```
hashy[:field2][:value] = '' if hashy[:field2][:value].nil?
# or
hashy[:field2][:value] = '' unless hashy[:field2].has_key?(:value)
```

Then your hash will be:

```rb
{:field1=>{:display=>"abc", :value=>"def"}, :field2=>{:display=>"abc2", :value=>""}, :field3=>{:display=>"abc3", :value=>"def1"}}
```

You can parse the resulting hash into JSON

```rb
# require 'json' # Don't forget to require json
require 'json'

JSON.generate(hashy)
# or
h.to_json

# => "{\"field1\":{\"display\":\"abc\",\"value\":\"def\"},\"field2\":{\"display\":\"abc2\",\"value\":\"\"},\"field3\":{\"display\":\"abc3\",\"value\":\"def1\"}}"
```